# Type Error i is undefined

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-draggable

Am using jquery draggable collision plugin which throws the error on loading the page that is "Type Error i is undefined"

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type= "text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type= "text/javascript" src="js/jquery-collision.min.js"></script>
<script type= "text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-draggable-collision.min.js"></script>
<script type= "text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="header">Sprite Generator</div>

<div id="droppable" >
<div id="overLay">Drop Files Here</div>
</div>
<div id="cssDetails">
<div id="cssHead">CSS Data</div>
</div>
<div id="errorMessage"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code I use. Kindly help, am not aware what is going wrong here.

Comment: Do you have a jsFiddle we can review?  Or any info about the error?   Maybe a webpage we can check if it's too complex for fiddle?

Comment: @Charlie74 If you render this page itself you will see errors in console

Comment: @ Patsy Issa If I use the collision.min.js and ui-draggable-collision.min.js along with ui.js this error occurs. But if specific ui files like droppable, draggable, etc separately included it executes well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error lies in the draggable collision plugin file. Each time the method `.data("draggable")` is called, an undefined value is returned.

There is a slight difference between jQuery UI 1.9.2 and 1.10.3. In this last version, `.data("draggable")` has been replaced by `.data("ui-draggable")`.

You should :

- Either use an old version of jQuery UI plugin,
- or use the last version, then replace `.data("draggable")` by `.data("ui-draggable")` in the jquery-ui-draggable-collision.min.js file.

In my own case, I used the second solution. But your case may be different, since I don't know which version of jQuery UI plugin you are using now.

Comment: Thanks! Got it to work with jQuery 1.10.2 & jQuery UI 1.10.3.

Answer (score 1):

The README for jQuery UI Draggable Collision reads:

> Load jquery-ui-draggable-collision and its dependencies:
>
> ```
> <script src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
> <script src="ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
> <script src="ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
> <script src="ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
> <script src="ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
> <script src="jquery-collision-1.0.2.js"></script>
> <script src="jquery-ui-draggable-collision-1.0.2.js"></script>
> ```

It doesn't explain *why* you need to load modules separately, but my suspicion is there's a conflict going on somewhere.  I'd try including the specific individual files (core, widget, mouse, draggable, collision, and ui-draggable-collision) and see if that works.  Without more information in your question, it's hard for me to try a set of specific things, but this may be your best bet.

Comment: Its working when I include specific individual files and I did it before posting this question. But my question is why it is not working when including the whole ui.js file ?

Comment: Likely because there is a conflict.  I assume the README suggests doing these separately because there's a conflict somewhere in jquery ui.  I'm not sure where, though.